# How can I mark Mail as read in MS Outlook2010?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, outlook, outlook-2010

I am developing an application, in which I need to read the content (mail body) of the incoming mail. For this, I am using below code to trigger the event, every time when new mail comes -

```
outLookApp.NewMailEx += new ApplicationEvents_11_NewMailExEventHandler(MailExtractor.outLookApp_NewMailEx);
```

I am using MS outlook2010?

How can I mark Mail as read those are going through this application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `UnRead` property of the Outlook `MailItem`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.unread(v=office.14).aspx